# What would you call two elements in an array that are only related to each other through their positions?

Tags: naming

I have an array that holds valuable data related to what I stored in a setup / onboarding process:

```
$imported_headers = [ 'headers_2', 'headers_3' ];
```

Given the fact that these  elements are from the same category but **their [each element's] content varies by a lot at times** and each of them only holds references that allow me to go deeper in the history chain for other processes, what best should I call these 2 items?

*Twins* doesn't work - they're not the same nor do I want people who use my function to retrieve them to think of them this way; *Sisters* - same, don't want to denote any kind of **intended similiarity of the said components structure / values**.

Neighbors? `$imported_headers` will sometimes have upwards of 10 items in it, but this function will precisely only retrieve the latest 2, neighbors would have a kind of finality - supposedly there's no more neighbors if my function is called and it retrieves only these 2 values.

My reasoning for asking a seemingly useless question, besides tormenting SE's purists, is that this function is part of 10+ functions that tie my system together and it'll be widely used both by my system and anyone that wants to use my API, it has to be descriptive and clear. Currently my function name is `getSisterComponents`. **It matters a lot that I can have a conversation-like technical explanation about my code with other developers where I don't have to explain each function even if the said developer might not be aware of its implementation.**

An example of exactly how my system works:

[image]

If I call `myPerfectFunctionName( 'headers' );` it should return the following array: `['demo-3_headers', 'demo-5_headers']`, as such, anyone that sees / uses this function will understand immediately that I'm querying the back-end system to look for the installed components from a category and pull the latest 2 installed items from the said category.

I want it to express that the function is a main, important query and that these 2 values are vital to whatever the process that's using the function to retrieve them does. Simply naming it 'getLastTwoInstalledComponentsByCategory` doesn't express usage and is generic.

Comment: Honestly, *"elements from the same category but are not alike"* is a description which is far too vague to give you a sensible answer, that could fit to **any** array holding elements of the same type. There is IMHO too much missing context for outsiders to do anything else here like playing guessing games.

Comment: @DocBrown I changed to what I actually meant "from the same category but that don't have the same content".

Comment: Still not clear. What is the (index)numeric relationship between the array elements? Or is this meaningless after all and is it about latest creation times of the referenced objects?

Comment: @MartinMaat The relationship between the elements is that they're in the same category. If I query my system for the key `headers`, it's going to give me these values. It stops there.  This `headers` key represents a category of modules out of which these modules are part of, but when I call the function to retrieve the latest 2 items in the array, it has to be descriptive, something like `getLatestNeighborItemsForComponentCategory` but I wouldn't use "neighbor" for the reasons stated in my original question.

Comment: Okay, Naming is hard, which I understand is why you've asked. But for this to work I (and the greater we) need context. A Name is the best representation of that context. With what you have currently stated the best name I can suggest is to just use an indexed array. Literally 0 and 1, because at this level of abstraction they are *Sisters* and have no bearing on each other. What context I need is the kind of data in the first "sister" vs. the kind of data in the second "sister". Also **I couldn't care less about your implementation** I trust you have your reasons, but we do need that context.

Comment: @Kain0_0 I did my best to explain with an illustration and added yet another angle: it's not a complex process, I just want whoever's going to use this function to immediately understand "ah, ok, I'm pulling these 2 values because they're vital".

Comment: @Kain0_0 Cousins? It denotes a link somewhere but not close enough for it to be that meaningful, but then again cousins also denotes a somewhat distant position in the array and we have `x, x+1` positions here which are right next to each other.

Comment: If you want *"anyone to understand immediately that I'm querying the back-end system to look for the installed components from a category and pull the latest 2 installed items from the said category"*, why not call your function `getLatestTwoHeadersFromCategory`? And I would call a data structure for pairs of headers just `HeaderPairs`. If you use such a structure, your function could also be named `getLatestHeaderPairFromCategory`

Comment: @DocBrown You're right. "pair" is a good choice, but since I can query other things besides headers, it'll have to be something like `getLatestComponentPairFromCategory`.

Answer (score 2):

> I want it to express that the function is a main, important query and that these 2 values are vital to whatever the process that's using the function to retrieve them does

Anything that important should be wrapped in its own class, perhaps called "Context." (In an ideal world, the context would be injected, but that's not relevant to the question at hand).

The Context class could expose two members, for example "PrimaryHeader" and "SecondaryHeader" or whatever name is appropriate for your problem domain. I would discourage the use of terms like "Component," "Brother," or "Sister" because those terms are meaninglessly ambiguous to anyone trying to learn your API, and people really do not want to learn any more terminology than absolutely necessary.

If they are truly logically unrelated, the primary and secondary headers should be obtainable separately, via separate class members. If there is a performance issue that makes you want to retrieve both at the same time, solve that problem with read-ahead caching (e.g. when the caller requests one, get both and save it for later. Or keep it simple and just populate both in Context's constructor). But don't force the caller to deal with what is really an implementation detail. That is called a [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction).

Answer (score 1):

The last and penultimate (the one before) / the two last / trailing children or siblings.

Child and sibling are the conventional notions.